# Read many values from one variable in config file. I want with ksh connect oracle db and make query

Tags: oracle, shell, variables, config, ksh

> Hi all,
>
> I need write script who reads variables from config files and connect
>   to Oracle db and after than do some queries and save results in
>   logfile.
>
> To connect db in my file is line
>
> sqlplus $Username/$Userpassword@Enviroment
>
> than I have function who execute one query and result save in logfile.
>
> While I have only one Enviroment its all work fine, but I need upgrade
>   this script who takes enviroment values from config file and run in
>   loop.
>
> In config file I have information like this
>
> Username=user Userpassword=pass Enviroments=Env1,Env2,Env3,EnvX
>
> Problem is that skript read Enviroment=Env1,Env2Env3,EnvX like one
>   value and don't split like ... Enviroment=Env1 and connect db and do
>   some jobs
>
> Enviroment=Env2   and connect db and do some jobs ....
>
> I have for loop who looks like this
>
> for Test in $(echo $Enviroment | sed "s/,/ /g") do echo "do some job"
>   done
>
> with this function i split enviroment names. Programm understand after
>   " , " starts next variable.
>
> Its works but only in script end. In program begining where program
>   read $Enviroment variable  takes all like one value and there starts
>   errors..  I can't figured how to put this function into my script and
>   write all in big loop

I hope you understand what problem I have.
I expected loop who reeds variables from config file and if there is lot of environments this loop take one by one variable value and put in code.

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you create a [mcve] showing your problem, along with expected and actual output. Right now, it is challenging to put the pieces together from your text. Also, please use code formatting using back ticks (\`) for code and file contents.

Answer (score 2):

As rtoijala said, you should always provide a minimal reproducible example. That said, using what I understood from your text I've made that code. Hopefully it might give you some pointers.

Using a configuration file as :

```
Username=user1 Userpassword=pass1 Enviroments=Env11,Env12,Env13,Env1X
Username=user2 Userpassword=pass2 Enviroments=Env21,Env22,Env23
Username=user3 Userpassword=pass3 Enviroments=Env31,Env32
```

This code :

```
#!/bin/ksh

while read -r a b c; do
        locUser=${a#*=}
        locPasswd=${b#*=}
        locEnv=${c#*=}
        arEnv=( ${locEnv//,/ } )
        for i in ${!arEnv[@]}; do
                print "sqlplus $locUser/$locPasswd@${arEnv[$i]}"
        done
done < ./config.txt
```

will produce :

```
sqlplus user1/pass1@Env11
sqlplus user1/pass1@Env12
sqlplus user1/pass1@Env13
sqlplus user1/pass1@Env1X
sqlplus user2/pass2@Env21
sqlplus user2/pass2@Env22
sqlplus user2/pass2@Env23
sqlplus user3/pass3@Env31
sqlplus user3/pass3@Env32
```

Comment: Edited as proposed. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks Andre. I fix this with one big FOR loop. But I will try later with while loop like you write. This was my first question. Next time I will try write more clear my question.